# Combining LIKE and EXISTS?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-like, exists

Here is the database I'm using: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ArJekOQpal0JFIr1h3NXYcFVngnCNUxg/view?usp=sharing

**Find the papers whose title contain the string 'data' and where at least one author is
from the department with deptnum 100. List the panum and title of these papers. You
must use the EXISTS operator. Ensure your query is case-insensitive.**

I'm unsure how to output the total number of papers for each academic.

My attempt at this question:

```
SELECT panum, title
FROM department NATURAL JOIN paper
WHERE UPPER(title) LIKE ('%data%') AND EXISTS (SELECT deptnum FROM 
department WHERE deptnum = 100);
```

This seems to come up empty. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, can LIKE and EXISTS be combined?

Thank you.

Comment: Please edit your question and include sample data, only for the tables involved in your query.  Don't show us a massive dump, just a few rows of sample data will do.  Then, show us the expected output from your query.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `natural join`!  It is an abomination because it does not make use of explicitly declared foreign key relationships.  Explicitly list your `join` keys, so the queries are more understandable and more maintainable.

That said, your subquery is the problem.  I would expect a query more like this:

```
SELECT p.panum, p.title
FROM paper p
WHERE lower(p.title) LIKE '%data%' AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM authors
              WHERE a.author = p.author AND -- or whatever the column should be
                    a.deptnum = 100
             );
```

Answer (score 0):

Since they are requiring `EXISTS`, the operator needs to be applied to `author`, not `department` table. The query inside `EXISTS` needs to be correlated with the query on papers, so there should be no `JOIN` on the top level:

```
SELECT p.PANUM, p.TITLE
FROM paper p
WHERE p.Title LIKE ('%data%') AND EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM author a
    JOIN academic ac ON ac.ACNUM=a.ACNUM
    WHERE a.PANUM=p.PANUM AND ac.DEPTNUM=100
)
```

Note that since `author` table lacks `DEPTNUM`, you do need a join inside the `EXISTS` query to bring in a row of `academic` for its `DEPTNUM` column.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase `UPPER(title) LIKE ('%data%')` is never going to find any rows, since an uppercase version of whatever is in title will never contain the lowercase letters `data`.

Answer (score 0):

```
select p.TITLE,p.PANUM   from PAPER p where TITLE   like '%data%'
AND EXISTS( 
SELECT * FROM AUTHOR a join ACADEMIC d
      on d.ACNUM=a.ACNUM where d.DEPTNUM=100 AND a.PANUM=p.PANUM)
```